# I set wlan but the no ping over wifi

Tags: wifi

I set `wlan0` config (uncomment `bcm43` from blacklist):

```
root@NanoPC-T2:~# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5e:a5:4f:cc:83:8a
          inet addr:195.165.101.232  Bcast:195.165.101.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7ca8:5fff:fecc:738a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21331 errors:0 dropped:11440 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1734079 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:64331 (64.3 KB)
          Interrupt:48

ip6tnl0   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          NOARP  MTU:1452  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3958 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3958 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:293200 (293.2 KB)  TX bytes:293200 (293.2 KB)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e2:47:73:46:b9:8f
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 15:a1:a2:a3:c5:4e
          inet6 addr: fe80::25d4:a2ff:fea3:c54e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)
```

and also set `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
 cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 195.165.101.232
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 195.165.101.254

iface wlan0 inet static
address 195.165.101.232
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 195.165.101.254
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and `wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
 cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=CN
network={
ssid="V01"
psk="123456"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

and I do this also `ifconfig wlan0 up` but when I disconnect Ethernet I can not connect or ping to that IP from wifi.

```
nmcli c
NAME      UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE
V01    0c4435f2-7301-8574-9b1b-deb7fd2a7603  802-11-wireless  --
V1 1  80b21422-c7ea-568c-8b4c-6f1d8a9dc9f8  802-11-wireless  --
```

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and `uname -a` ? what is the content of your blacklist file?

Comment: Please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/401187/edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the same IP address on several interfaces (you may combine several interfaces to one using bonding, though).

Thus (as you can see in your `ifconfig` output) `wlan0` is not assigned an IPv4 address.

Comment: The `wpa_supplicant.conf` need formatting , a wep key is used and the `key_mgmt`  is set `WPA-PSK`  instead of `NONE` , also a `blacklist` file is used , maybe the right module is included on the blacklist file.

Comment: @GAD3R These are additional problems. But without the module there would be no `wlan0` interface at all.

Comment: @HaukeLaging thanks for reply, but how can I force wlan0 to use IPV4? also I changed the wlan0 IP too.

Comment: @H.Ghassami You have to assign it a valid (i.e. not used elsewhere) IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces` and, of course, the configuration for `wpa_supplicant` must be correct.

Comment: thanks for reply. how I correct the wpa_supplicant?my ip is correct now.

Comment: @H.Ghassami I am not familiar with wpa_supplicant thus I cannot help you with that.

Comment: @GAD3R said to uncomment bcm43, I uncomment it and also I edit `ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
#country=CN
network={
ssid="V01"
psk="PASS"
}
`then it works. thanks all

Comment: @H.Ghassami to get the information about the card driver and the kernel driver in use  we need the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` to see the compatibility with the kernel we need `uname -a` , the blacklist file should de written if you are sure about the right wifi module

Comment: @GAD3R: `root@NanoPC-T2:~# uname -a
Linux NanoPC-T2 3.4.39-s5p4418 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 1 13:21:10 HKT 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
` and `root@NanoPC-T2:~# lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
-bash: lspci: command not found
`

Comment: @H.Ghassami it is better to edit here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/401187/edit